# Restrict Previous api Request in search functioanlity

Tags: reactjs

i am using react js,
have search field

```
   <input 
        type="search" 
        onChange={this.updateSearchText}/>
```

function updateSearch:

```
updateSearchText = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        searchText: e.target.value
    }, function () {
            fetch("https://api.example.com/search/?key"+ this.state.searchText)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.props.searchResult(response.data)
                })
    });
};
```

my issue is that if type text very quickly, first letter triggers search request and it update the props after second request has sent. so i get only first letters result.
how can i restrict first request if i type second one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "throttling" and "debouncing" your input. You can refer https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/ to understand it.

One of the solution that worked for me was to create "queue". The purpose of the queue was if we add a task to the queue, the task goes in front of the queue and if we add a second task to the queue, the task goes in the second position. If we add a third task to the queue, the task replaces the second.

So there is a maximum of two tasks in the queue. As soon as the first task has ended, the second task is executed etc.

So you always have the same result, and you limit your api calls in function of many parameters. If the user has a slow internet connexion, the first request will take some time to execute, so there won't be a lot of requests.